# format old file to org-indent-mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I want to convert file created without (org-indent-mode) to (org-indent-mode) format. Mostly it's additional 2,3,4 spaces. I was trying to fix it with string-replace. But maybe somebody have better idea?
That's example part:
[image]

And with turned on (org-indent-mode)

[image]

Comment: `org-indent-mode` is not a "format": it does not physically add spaces to your file. It's a minor mode that dynamically does "virtual" indentation, so it changes the *appearance* of the buffer. Try opening the file and doing `M-x org-indent-mode` once or twice and see what happens.

Comment: I understand. But without org-indent-mode I was creating files like on first picture - text under headlines is indent by added spaces. And now when I turned on org-indent-mode which indention is not based on spaces & tabs - file look like on second picture. It's not properly align.
So I have to remove all previously added spaces & tabs.

Comment: In the first headline is that a single list with four items or is it a two-level list with one item on the first level and three items in the second level? To me, it seems to be the latter, in which case, it is rendered correctly and you don't want to change anything. OTOH, the contents of the second and third headline have extra spaces which need to be removed. If that is the case, it will be very hard to make the changes that you want using string matching because you will not have the context: you'd need a full org-mode parser to be able to figure out in which context to make the change.

Comment: Personally, I would worry about it a file at a time: when you open the file, assess the situation and fix it up by hand (or with a small set of heuristics which you might want to collect in a file for further use if you think you'll encounter the same situation again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I roughly made two functions that add or remove hard indentations.

```
(defun org-add-hard-indentation (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (while
        (let ((indent-size
               (progn
                 (when (re-search-forward "^\\*+ " nil t)
                   (length (match-string 0))))))
          (when indent-size
            (let ((start
                   (progn
                     (next-line)
                     (move-beginning-of-line 1)
                     (point)))
                  (end
                   (progn
                     (if (re-search-forward "^\\*+ " nil t)
                         (progn (previous-line) (move-end-of-line 1))
                       (end-of-buffer))
                     (point))))

              (indent-rigidly start end (* indent-size arg))))
          indent-size))))

(defun org-delete-hard-indentation (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (org-add-hard-indentation (- arg)))
```

However, `org-delete-hard-indentation` only works when hard indentations are consistent. In your example, list items are not indented, but text in the second and third headings are indented, so the example is inconsistent.

In addition, the proposed functions are not sophisticated. Therefore, do not use `org-add-hard-indentation` / `org-delete-hard-indentation` when hard indentations do / don't exist already.

Answer (score 1):

Org mode already has functions to remove or add hard indentations.
`org-unindent-buffer` removes hard indentations in a buffer.
`org-indent-region` adds hard indentations in a selected region when `org-indent-mode` is disabled.